# Why is adaptive SQL not working with df persist?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[4]").appName("Test")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled", "true")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes", "50m")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionNum", "1")
                        .config("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum", "1024")
                        .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.csv("<Input File Path>")
val df1 = df.distinct()
df1.persist() // On removing this line. Code works as expected
df1.write.csv("<Output File Path>")
```

I have an input file of size 2 GB which is read as 16 partitions of size 128 MB each. I have enabled adaptive SQL to coalesce partitions after the shuffle

Without df1.persist, df1.write.csv writes 4 partition files of 50 MB each which is expected
[Without persist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDxpV.png)

If I include df1.persist, Spark is writing 200 partitions(adaptive coalesce not working)
[With persist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W13hA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.config("spark.sql.optimizer.canChangeCachedPlanOutputPartitioning", "true")

Adding this config worked
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-38172?filter=reportedbyme